# GD/Imagick doesn't save my image

Tags: php, android, gd, imagick

I want to send an image from android and save it trought a php code in my server. Because I need to protect my server I need to reprocess the image so I have to use GD or Imagick. Image is sent encoded in base64. In the php file is decoded and if I use:

```
$img=base64_decode($img);
$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $img);
fclose($file);
```

image is saved in the server. If I use Imagick or GD my image isn't saved and the php files returns nothing, even if I insert an echo after it. Any help? In GD I was using:

```
$img=base64_decode($img);
$imageinfo = getimagesize($img);
if($imageinfo['mime'] == 'image/gif'{
    $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
    imagejpeg($img, ""testt.jpg", 80);
}
```

and in Imagick:

```
$img=base64_decode($img);
$img = imagick($img); //neither if I use a path of an image saved in my server 
                      //works
$mime = mime_content_type($img);
    switch ($mime):
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $ext = '.jpg';
            break;
    endswitch;

$img->stripImage();
$img->writeImage(""testt".$ext);
$img->clear();
$img->destroy();
```

Comment: The 2nd and the 3rd code block have a syntax error. Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: your code is full of syntax errors.

Comment: I see an " extra in imagick and gd code but it's only because I added accidentally while copying here.

Comment: Also `if($imageinfo['mime'] == 'image/gif'{` is missing closing parenthesis. And why are you trying to create from jpg when you have gif ? Please post real code

Comment: Alright, my fault. I deleted the extra elseif and I put the wrong function. Anyway, the point wasn't that. The point was that with the simpliest function the result of the php page was "" (I know that because I see all the info that the php page replies in my android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagick only works on files, you can't give a handle to it unfortunately, so:

```
$img=base64_decode($img);
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'tempimage_'); 
$file = fopen($filename, 'wb');
fwrite($file, $img);
fclose($file);

$img = imagick($filename);  
$mime = mime_content_type($img);
    switch ($mime):
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $ext = '.jpg';
            break;
   endswitch;

$img->stripImage();
$img->writeImage("testt".$ext);
$img->clear();
$img->destroy();
```

This, in theory, should work.

Comment: Correcting the double " as dev-null pointed, it doesn't work. In my android app I get as response nothing, "", and the image is not create it. Is it because I use xampp?

Comment: Depends if you have the imagick module installed and enabled on that XAMPP - you can find it in the right click menu a.f.a.i.r. - do you have anything in the log files of XAMPP?

Comment: I reinstall it all because I was very confused and I get the last version of XAMPP. Result: Imagick on windows works. Imagick on php no. I know I need to put an php file on ext folder and then modify php.ini and reboot apache server but where is the last version of that php file?

Comment: it's a module file, it should be already part of XAMPP. what about GD?

Comment: With GD seems that it works with your code. I suppose that calling imagejpeg will be enough and I won't need to use the temp file but I haven't tried yet. Anyway, is it secure to use this function to prevent attacks like http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070604/passing-malicious-php-through-getimagesize/ ?

Comment: Check md5sum of the two files (the temporary, and the one saved by GD) - if they differ, they are _likely_ safe, if they're the same, they're _likely_ unsafe. And yes, of course you can remove the temp file afterwards.

Comment: But md5 isn't secure. No? I read about that md5 was hacked time ago.  Why do you want to compare them? If file can't be written is a bad file and the temp file will always deleted. My point was that may be the second that the temp file will exist would be a backdoor for a hacker.

Comment: No, the temp file would be only a backdoor if it was actually served by someone, but that directory isn't even servable through the webserver usually... Comparsion through md5 hash was to be done to check if GD actually did something with the file, or, realizing that there's no work to be done, it saved the original file under a new name instead of creating a new one from pixel data.